# Heatmap with specific axis labels coloured

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am trying to plot a heatmap with 2 columns of data from a pandas dataframe. However, I would like to use a 3rd column to label the x axis, ideally by colour though another method such as an additional axis would be equally suitable. My dataframe is:

```
    MUT   SAMPLE   VAR             GROUP
    True  s1       1_1334442_T     CC002
    True  s2       1_1334442_T     CC006
    True  s1       1_1480354_GAC   CC002
    True  s2       1_1480355_C     CC006
    True  s2       1_1653038_C     CC006
    True  s3       1_1730932_G     CC002
```

...

Just to give a better idea of the data; there are 9 different types of 'GROUP', ~60,000 types of 'VAR' and 540 'SAMPLE's. I am not sure if this is the best way to build a heatmap in python but here is what I figured out so far:

```
pivot = pd.crosstab(df_all['VAR'],df_all['SAMPLE'])
sns.set(font_scale=0.4)
g = sns.clustermap(pivot, row_cluster=False, yticklabels=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap="YlGnBu", cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

I am not sure how to get 'GROUP' to display along the x-axis, either as an additional axis or just colouring the axis labels? Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm not sure if the 'MUT' column being a boolean variable is an issue here, df_all is 'TRUE' on every 'VAR' but as pivot is made, any samples which do not have a particular 'VAR' are filled as 0, others are filled with 1. My aim was to try and cluster samples with similar 'VAR' profiles. I hope this helps.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything further? Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take look at this example. You can give a list or a dataframe column to the `clustermap` function. By specifying either the `col_colors` argument or the `row_colors` argument you can give colours to either the rows or the columns based on that list.

In the example below I use the iris dataset and make a pandas series object that specifies which colour the specific row should have. That pandas series is given as an argument for `row_colors`.

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
lut = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = species.map(lut)
g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors,row_cluster=False)
```

This code results in the following image.

You may need to tweak a bit further to also include a legend for the colouring for groups.

[image]

Comment: This is helpful to know that this can be done. However, the structure of my df is different to iris as I have made a pivot/crosstab of 2 of the columns of the original df and am plotting a heatmap based on the output of this. I would need to re-add add another column for 'GROUP' to make my df equivalent to the iris. I am struggling to do this using pandas methods. I could initiate a new column then iterate over the df and for each row add which 'GROUP' to the new column but it seems very cumbersome - do you know a pandas approach to this?